# Cluster analysis in R (hclust): how to determine which variable is driving the clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, hclust

I'm using hclust to perform a cluster analysis of plant species cover data across sampling sites.

My study observed percent cover of 55 species at 100 sites. Plant cover at each site was measured in cover classes of 0-4, where 0 is absent, '1' is 1-25% cover ...'4' is 76-100% cover.

I'm using Euclidian distance to measure species cover dissimilarity between sites, and I want to know which plant species is driving the grouping of each branch of the dendrogram. See sample df & code below; each row represents a site.

In the simplified example, I can see that sp1 is driving the association of sites 3 & 4. In my very large dataset, how could I determine which species is/are driving the associations at different levels of my dendrogram?

Please let me know if I can clarify. Thanks for your help!

```
library(tidyverse)

site <- c(1:10)
sp1 <- c(0,1,4,4,3,3,2,1,0,2)
sp2 <- c(4,3,0,0,2,2,3,2,1,3)
sp3 <- c(3,2,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,3)
sp4 <- c(2,4,1,0,1,2,3,4,3,1)
df <- data.frame(site, sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4)

species <- select(df, sp1:sp4)

dend <- species %>% 
  dist(method = "euclidean") %>% 
  hclust(method = "ward.D") %>% 
  as.dendrogram()

plot(dend, ylab = "Euclidan Distance")
```

Comment: Not sure about specific branches of the dendrogram, but for differences in clusters [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77689/estimating-the-most-important-features-in-a-k-means-cluster-partition) might be helpful. It is for k-means but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like an ANOVA would be the way to go, but I'm a little weak on my understanding of what I should input into ANOVA; would it be Euclidian distance matrix?

Comment: No problem. I'd say the idea is to do multiple ANOVAs, each time with a single feature, which in your case is the each of the species (Given the discrete nature of your data you could also try a chi-square test instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up:
I ended up assigning the sites in each cluster to an arbitrary Association group, and then running an indicator species analysis on the Association group using the multipatt function from indicspecies. This allowed me to identify the species that were significantly driving the clustering of the different groups.

```
clusters <- df %>% mutate(Association = 
                  case_when(site %in% c(3, 4)~1, 
                            site %in% c(2, 8, 9)~2, 
                            site %in% c(1, 5, 6, 7, 10)~3))

abundance = clusters[2:5]
association = clusters$Association

indicator_r.g = multipatt(abundance, association, func = "r.g", control = how(nperm=9999))
summary(indicator_r.g)


Multilevel pattern analysis
 ---------------------------

 Association function: r.g
 Significance level (alpha): 0.05

 Total number of species: 4
 Selected number of species: 4 
 Number of species associated to 1 group: 3 
 Number of species associated to 2 groups: 1 

 List of species associated to each combination: 

 Group 1  #sps.  1 
    stat p.value  
sp1 0.82  0.0193 *

 Group 2  #sps.  1 
     stat p.value  
sp4 0.832  0.0161 *

 Group 3  #sps.  1 
     stat p.value  
sp3 0.781  0.0317 *

 Group 2+3  #sps.  1 
     stat p.value  
sp2 0.844  0.0293 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```